# Import-Module could not find part of the path

Tags: powershell

Working on a corporate laptop with no access to local admin but with the execution policy set to unrestricted, when trying to import the SQLPS cmdlets I receive an error indicating a problem with the path, shown below.

Why is the import-module command looking at my AppData\Local\Temp folder?

[image: Error Importing Module]

Comment: Looks like it's not Import-Module looking for that path but rather the module itself.

Comment: @Deadly-Bagel: reading suggests SQL Server Management Studio is required to be installed for these cmdlets to be available; is requesting re-install of SSMS my best approach to resolve, or can you help me guide my supporting service desk people to resolution?

Comment: Reinstall might be the way to go, unfortunately I don't have any experience with the module and cmdlets for SQL as they really don't like Server 2008 R2 x64 so I've had to write my own using the .NET objects.

Answer (score 0):

If a reinstall of SSMS does not do the trick, try installing the `PowerShellTools.msi` package of the SQL Server feature pack that corresponds with the latest server you will be working on.

[SQL Server 2014](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42295)

[SQL Server 2016](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52676)

I would also recommend running `Get-Module Sqlps | Format-Table -Property ModuleType,Name,Path` to check if there are multiple copies of the module and remove them as needed.